# retrieving video from database using php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, video

I am trying to figure out how to retrieve video_link from my database after users select the video using a html form. 2 videos are uploaded into my database, the original video and a compressed video, depending on user connection. The appropriate video will be embed in html 5 video tag in viewvideo.php however because ajax is expecting a response in             **$( "#speed" ).val( html );** i dun think i can embed the video in viewvideo.php

So my question is what should i do now? where should i retrieve the video_link and embed the video?

This is my coding now.

I have a html form that retrieve user connection speed and video_id that user wish to watch and using ajax to post the form data

Html form

```
<form action="viewvideo.php" method="post" >
                <br/>
                Please select the video
                <br/>

                <select name="video_id">
                    <?php
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                        {
                    ?>       
                                      <option value="<?php echo $row['video_id']?>">
                    <?php echo $row['videoname']?>
                                      </option>         
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>

                <br />  
                <input type="text" id="speed" name="speed" value="">
                <input type="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
                </form>
```

Ajax

```
  $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "viewvideo.php",
      data: {speedMbps: speedMbps,
      video_id: $('[name="video_id"').val()},
      cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
        $( "#speed" ).val( html );
});
```

viewvideo.php

```
  if(isset($_POST['video_id']) && isset($_POST['speedMbps'] )){
                        $id = trim($_POST['video_id']);
                        $speed = $_POST['speedMbps'];
                        echo $id;

                        $result = mysqli_query($dbc , "SELECT `video_id`, `video_link` FROM `video480p` WHERE `video_id`='".$id."'");
                        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                        if (($speed < 100) && ($count>0)) {     //if user speed is less than 100 retrieve 480p quailtiy video   

                            //does it exist?
                            //if($count>0){
                                //exists, so fetch it in an associative array
                                $video_480p = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                                //this way you can use the column names to call out its values. 
                                //If you want the link to the video to embed it;
                                echo $video_480p['video_link'];                     
                                }

                            else{
                                //does not exist
                            }

        ?>

                        <video id="video" width="640" height="480" controls autoplay>
                        <source src="<?php echo $video_480p['video_link']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                        </video>
                        <br />

                        <?php

                        $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc , "SELECT `video_id`, `video_link` FROM `viewvideo` WHERE `video_id`='".$video_id."'");
                        $count2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

                        // retrieve original video
                         if (($speed >= 100) && ($count2 >0)) { 
                                //does it exist?
                                    //if($count2>0){
                                        //exists, so fetch it in an associative array
                                        $video_arr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
                                        //this way you can use the column names to call out its values. 
                                        //If you want the link to the video to embed it;
                                        echo $video_arr['video_link'];                      
                                        }
    else{
                                    //does not exist

                                }
        ?>

                        <video id="video" width="640" height="480" controls autoplay>
                        <source src="<?php echo $video_arr['video_link']; ?>" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                        </video>
                        <br />

        <?php

                    mysqli_close($dbc);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want video to be accessible to user, then you must put actual video (MP4) files in public directory where browser can download them. So video_link must contains actual URL accessible to user. If videos are not in public directory, then user cannot access them directly or you can embed video binary data in URL with data: protocol

```
 data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<video data>
```

For example

```
<?php
    function getVideoURLString($file, $type) { 
         return 'data:video/' . $type . ';base64,' .
                base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)); 
    }
?>
```

Then in HTML

```
<video ...>        
     <source type="video/mp4" src="<?php echo getVideoURLString($filename, "mp4");"> 
</video>
```

Embedding video data in URL has drawback that it may takes very long time to load HTML.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question... i can embed the video if i send my form using form post instead of ajax post. when i used ajax $( "#speed" ).val( html ); expect a return value so my embed video in viewvideo.php don't work