# Passing javascript value to html

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is related to my previous question: [retrieving video from database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35166946/retrieving-video-from-database-using-php)

On the previous question i pass the **speedMbps** in javascript using a `ajax` form and $( "#speed" ).val( html ); expect a return value so i am unable to embed my html code in viewvideo.php.

I thought of a different way to pass the speedMbps into my php.

Passing the value speedMbps into my html form which can used the method POST to sent the data to my php file.

```
var imageAddr = "testimage.jpg"; 
var downloadSize = 2097152; //bytes

window.onload = function() {
    var oProgress = document.getElementById("speed");
    oProgress.value = "Loading the image, please wait...";
    window.setTimeout(MeasureConnectionSpeed, 1);
};

function MeasureConnectionSpeed() {
    var oProgress = document.getElementById("speed");
    var startTime, endTime;
    var download = new Image();
    download.onload = function () {
        endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
        showResults();
    }

    download.onerror = function (err, msg) {
        oProgress.value = "Invalid image, or error downloading";
    }

    startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
    var cacheBuster = "?nnn=" + startTime;
    download.src = imageAddr + cacheBuster;


    function showResults() {
        var duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000;
        var bitsLoaded = downloadSize * 8;
        var speedBps = (bitsLoaded / duration).toFixed(2);
        var speedKbps = (speedBps / 1024).toFixed(2);
        var speedMbps = (speedKbps / 1024).toFixed(2);
        return speedMbps;
        oProgress.value = "Your connection speed is:        <br />" + 
           speedBps + " bps<br />"   + 
           speedKbps + " kbps<br />" + 
           speedMbps + " Mbps<br />";

document.getElementById("speed").value = speedMbps;
```

Html code

```
                <input type="text" id="speed" name="speed" value="">
```

viewvideo.php

```
$speed= $_POST['speed'];
```

Edited: when i echo $speed in my php file it does not get echo.. look like no value is pass from the javascript to my html form.

error on console is unexpected end of input on

```
document.getElementById("speed").value = speedMbps;
```

Comment: haven't you tried it yet? just submit the form

Comment: sadly it don't getting error Array callback has to contain indices 0 and 1 on $speed = $_POST('speed');

Comment: `$_POST` is an array, not a function. `[]` or `{}`. How does `viewvideo.php` relate to the HTML?

Comment: viewvideo.php contain my sql statement for retrieving my video from database and also my embed video code. the source code can be found in my previous question.

Comment: So there are 2 questions on the same question?

Comment: Nope. the previous question is asking on way to embed video after using ajax post. This question is on passing a JavaScript data to php file using html post. since using ajax i cant get the embed video to work. 2 different questions

Comment: Set the value from the JS into an html element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102418/discussion-between-mick-jack-and-chris85).

Comment: anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve the problem.

deleting `return speedMbps;` i manage to retrieve the value and pass the value into my php file.

Answer (score 0):

Your are using return statement before setting up data into form.

```
document.getElementById("speed").value = speedMbps;    return speedMbps;
```